# After Updating to Chrome 62, something weird is happening in tables css

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a `display:flex` container which contains a number of tables. I am using flex to keep them from breaking line. So as you can see, the tables are overlapping each other while in Firefox, Edge and Chrome 61 and below it was working fine.

[image]

How it is made(paint example):

[image]

After investigating what might be the bug, the overlapping table is not considering the outer table or even the div inside the  tag's width, it is directly considering the elements inside the div

table -> tr -> td -> div -> element

Problem Image and structure in elements tab for reference:

[image]

The workaround-fix I tried which worked added relevant width to inner elements :

[image]

The div which is block element in td with width of 100% automatic is not considered(marked in green):

[image]

I have opened a [ticket on Google Groups](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/pghnMqYma74;context-place=mydiscussions) too. I do not know if it is my mistake in applying the CSS or Chrome 62 Bug.

Edit: While you have to take account that this is only happening on last two. The others could also overlap with same bug but others are not so most likely Chrome 62 bug.

**Edit 2:** So found out that if I remove the floating right buttons on top it is again working fine!

[image]

**Edit 3:** Reproduced with JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f3227vff/ works fine on Firefox and Edge(Works exactly fine). Related to using float of button in table header.

**Edit 4:** As per suggestion of Kaiido, I have opened a chromium bug ticket on this issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=784680

Comment: @Kaiido Oh ok let me check on Canary if it is working! Thanks for update!

Comment: Just checked seems not fixed .. so this might be bug that got overlooked or not found .. let me see if i can reproduce this in a fiddle or codepen to confirm the bug

Comment: Ok, could also be an other, unrelated bug... If this is the case, the correct place to open issues is https://chromiumbugs.appspot.com and anyway, yes if you can manage to produce an [MCVE], that would be great for them and is mandatory for us (in SO)

Comment: Yep on it ! It is something related to button on float in header ..

Comment: @Kaiido added the jsfiddle and check the edit! Thanks!

Comment: Off topic: I expected something more exciting from this title. Like a twist. Written by M N Shamalayan or something like that.

Comment: Ok, so it's indeed not related at all. You might want to open an issue directly on [chromium's bug-tracker](https://chromiumbugs.appspot.com/) A workaround is to wrap your *ABC* textNode inside a `<div>`. https://jsfiddle.net/f3227vff/1/